# Search button is not working when search box is filled in

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a scraper in python with selenium to input an address in a searchbox and press the search button. When I run the scraper, it looks like that it fills in the address but when it press the search button to populate results then the site shows `please enter Address first`. Where I'm going wrong? The search address is embedded within `.send_keys()` to be tested. Thanks in advance for any help.

Site address: [website](http://findcompsnow.com/searchcomps/comps)

This is my attempt:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("replace with above address")

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "autocomplete"))).send_keys("5068 SW 141st Ave, Miramar, FL 33027")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "map-search"))).click()
driver.quit()
```

Btw, no `iframe` is there, so I thought it would be as simple as that but turn out the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your script as below:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "autocomplete"))).send_keys("5068 SW 141st Ave, Miramar, FL 33027")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "pac-item"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "map-search"))).click()
```

This should allow you to confirm your choice (the address you want to use) before searching for results

*Update*

If first suggestion doesn't work, try below one

```
input_address = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "autocomplete")))
input_address.send_keys("5068 SW 141st Ave, Miramar, FL 33027")
suggestion = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "pac-item")))
input_address.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
suggestion.click()
input_address.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer. I tried five times with your suggested portion but it still throws the same error `please enter Address first`.

Comment: Have no idea why chromedriver behaves differently from your side as code works well for me... Try updated answer. Does it makes any changes?

Comment: I'm also disturbed to see this issue. Btw, I could not find this class `pac-item` in that webpage. Gonna give it a try again.

Comment: `pac-item` should appears after string input. Do you see the suggestion below the input field after you sent string?

Comment: Yes sir, which shows `powered by google` or something but it doesn't stay when i try to inspect.

Comment: Yeah but it still there. The point is to click this element once it visible to confirm the suggested address. Does it contains only `"powered by google"`? You don't see anything else?

Comment: No sir, it contains the full address along with that line. However, it does not normally shows up. I could see this when I tried manually several times. However, It's hard to get in manually as well.

Comment: Yep, it disappeared each time you switch the focus... But in script it should be clicked right after appearence...

Comment: I tried with `post` request method using `requests` library and got success but the thing is there are two fields (additionally) to be filled in `latitude` and `longitude` to populate results that is why i tried with this but it seems to be my bad luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166165/discussion-between-andersson-and-shayan).